# Improving a function that returns a boolean

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am a beginner programmer. I want to learn how to write cleaner code. Is there a better way of writing the function below instead of having all the "Return True":

```
Public Function NegativeStatus() As Boolean
    If Status.Closed Then
        Return True
    ElseIf Status.Pending Then
        Return True
    ElseIf Status.Retry Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about reviewing/revising working code should be asked on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note that `NegativeStatus` isn’t a very helpful name. In fact, it’s positively obscure.

Comment: Your code simple enough. It is clean, readable and maintainable. Imagine in the future you will need to add two or three status states more. And in some cases even faster then answer @Albert(because he of using `Or`)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function NegativeStatus() As Boolean
  Return Status.Closed OR Status.Pending OR Status.Retry;
End Function
```

Since the function returns `True` if any of the conditions are met, one can use the Boolean `OR` to compress this.

Comment: I’d strongly prefer using `OrElse` for logical conditions, and reserve `Or` for bitwise operations only (I know that `Or` is defined as a boolean operator on `Boolean`s but I prefer using operators consistently).

Comment: Like @KonradRudolph, I would suggest `OrElse` rather than `Or`. In my case, the reason would be that it is a closer match to the original code - the later parts of the expression are not evaluated once an earlier one is found to be true. That would only matter if evaluating `Status.Closed` or `Status.Pending` had a side effect (which should not normally be expected).